# Подсветка кода в Android Studio для React Native

Tags: android-studio, настройка, react-native

Подскажите как включить подстветку кода в Android Studio?

Сейчас у меня подсвечивается только пара слов, и код выглядит вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подсветка кода у вас работает. Вам нужна цветовая схема с поддержкой React Native

Comment: @DmitryPetukhov А можно подробнее? Как начать пользоваться этой цветовой схемой?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать intellij IDEA Ultimate 2016.3
Там есть поддержка react native

Comment: Иван Шепеленко, см. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3404/199934